# Suggestion for designing product page in Wordpress

Tags: ajax, wordpress, genesis

I have a wordpress website and I am looking for the plugin suggestions for my Products page. I want that when user clicks on any company name on the [Products](http://greeninvites.com/product/) page, a page like [SubProducts](https://ibb.co/nQNP2F) should open up. On the 'SubProducts' page, there is a sidebar on the left. When user will click on 'Drills' in the sidebar, content should load in the 'Main Content' on the SubProducts page.

When user clicks on next product, it's content should load in the Main Content. I vaguely know that AJAX is useful for such purposes when we don't want to reload the page again.

Is there any plugin for this requirement. I don't want ecommerce plugins as I am not selling the products here.

I am also looking for some resources for implementing this in AJAX, I have found some pages but they are not doing what I want.

Please suggest.

Comment: you can do via ajax. It will not take long time to integrate.

Comment: I have to put time into learning AJAX. I was avoiding it for a long time.

Comment: there is no plugin what you want exactly. i think you have to learn